# Force mailto tag so it executes correct function after DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

My website has my email address on which people started using to send spam mails to. So I decided that I need to upgrade security for email addresses on the website.

I changed the website that you have to click on an email address in order to view it (or to click on it to open the mail client).

The unprocessed HTML looks like this:

```
<a href='#' address='mailto:person(at)example(dot)co(dot)za'>Click here to view</a>
```

The JavaScript looks like this and is executed on `window.load`

```
$("a[address]").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var address = $(this).attr("address");
        while(address.indexOf("(at)") !== -1){address = address.replace("(at)", "@")}
        while(address.indexOf("(dot)") !== -1){address = address.replace("(dot)", ".")}
        $(this).attr("href", "mailto:" + address);
        $(this).html(address);
    })
```

The user clicks on the `a` tag. The email address displays correctly.
But if I click it again (remember that the href is now `mailto:`) it does not open the mail client.

How can I force the browser to update the initial on-click event for a `mailto` tag.

Comment: check if the target has address attr, if so, return false and set the correct href and remove the address attr :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found a solution. I added the following code to the end of the JS:

`$(this).unbind("click");`

This is because the click is still bound after the tag is clicked the first time. It would be interesting still to know if there is a way to "force" open the mail client using JS.

The new JS code looks like this:

```
$("a[address]").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var address = $(this).attr("address");
        while(address.indexOf("(at)") !== -1){address = address.replace("(at)", "@")}
        while(address.indexOf("(dot)") !== -1){address = address.replace("(dot)", ".")}
        $(this).attr("href", "mailto:" + address);
        $(this).html(address);

       // this is the new code
        $(this).unbind("click");
    })
```

Comment: You can "force" open the mail client using javascript with `window.open('mailto:address@example.com');` or `location.href = 'mailto:address@example.com';`

Answer (score 2):

If you want clicking on the link to cause the link to be followed, don't say `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: I don't want the event to follow on the first click. This needs to happen only after the first click. So you click it the first time and it only displays the email address. The second time it should execute the mailto client

Comment: So do a test and only call `event.preventDefault();` conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element has an attribute and remove it once it has been clicked, then only `preventDefault` when the attribute is present.

```
$("a[address]").click(function (event) {
    if($(this).attr('address')){
        event.preventDefault();
        var address = $(this).attr("address");
        while(address.indexOf("(at)") !== -1){address = address.replace("(at)", "@")}
        while(address.indexOf("(dot)") !== -1){address = address.replace("(dot)", ".")}
        $(this).attr("href", "mailto:" + address);
        $(this).html(address);
        $(this).removeAttr('address');
    }
});
```

Comment: That solution would work yet, but then every time the user clicks on the tag it would have to run the code again, even if the first check if to see if the address attr is still present. The solution I proposed works better because it will remove the option of the function being run again and just use the browsers native behavior for the mailto tag. If I am not mistaken?